# Define symbol as UserID or UserId?

Tags: go

In Go I've seen some people defining symbols (methods, variables, etc) like this: `UserID`, `GetSomeURL()` with UPPERCASE letters of ids, urls, etc.

Is this a standard way?

Even my editor, that uses go-lint, warns me that I should change it (because I use UserId).

I read some of the golang source code https://golang.org/src/ and I never saw some like `UserID`.

Is this going to be another "tabs" vs "spaces" thing? LOL

I know this does not cause any problems compiling or any other problem, but I'm just trying get some "standard" on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UserID` and `GetSomeURL` (or simply `SomeULR()`) would be idiomatic.

Source: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms:

> Words in names that are initialisms or acronyms (e.g. "URL" or "NATO")
>   have a consistent case. For example, "URL" should appear as "URL" or
>   "url" (as in "urlPony", or "URLPony"), never as "Url". Here's an
>   example: ServeHTTP not ServeHttp.
>
> This rule also applies to "ID" when it is short for "identifier," so
>   write "appID" instead of "appId".

You are right, golint is useful to identify deviations from the standard naming convention - it's good to follow its advices (especially when the code is worked on by multiple people and coding style consistency is even more valuable).